# Are the inbox routes (`inbox_item`) missing some item types?

Tags: support, discussion, api, api-v2.2, inbox

Should there be more options for `item_type` in the "inbox" routes (they return  [inbox_item](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item))?

Shouldn't they return `answer` and `edit suggested` like the site's global inbox does? As shown in this screenshot:

[image: Site inbox has extra items]

Answer (score 2):

1) Answer is already in [the `inbox_item` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item). Note the entry for `item_type` in [the doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item):

> one of comment, chat_message, **new_answer**, careers_message, careers_invitations, meta_question, post_notice, or moderator_message

`new_answer` is returned whenever a new answer is posted to one of the authenticated user's questions.

2) `edit_suggested` is returned as part of [the `notification` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/notification), which also returns:

```
    accounts_associated                 moderator_message
    badge_earned                        new_privilege
    bounty_expired                      post_migrated
    bounty_expires_in_one_day           profile_activity
    bounty_expires_in_three_days        registration_reminder
    bounty_grace_period_started         reputation_bonus
    edit_suggested                      substantive_edit
    generic
```

So, **you have to call both one of the `/inbox` routes and one of the `/notifications` routes** to get the same information that's in the Stack Exchange "inbox".  But you normally want to do that anyway.

Comment: These are workarounds. Do you agree that there some deviation from the results shown in the website?

Comment: Those are not workarounds, that's the way it is.  Everything you asked for is already available, just classified slightly differently from the way the website *currently* does it.  Almost no API in the world has a one-to-one matchup with the corresponding website (I'm not aware of any API's that do).